# image profile facebook to base64 PHP

Tags: php, image, facebook, base64

I need to get the picture of the profile of facebook and convert to Base64. The version of PHP is 5.2.17 and I cannot use the last SDK.

I can login, get the picture and show it with this:

src="https://graph.facebook.com/$id/picture?type=large">

I´ve tried to save a copy of the image with this example: [file_get_contents() and Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251106/file-get-contents-and-curl), the url of the image is correct.

This is the url: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/16195072_104262870090313_5077585589040998026_n.jpg?oh=xxxxx&oe=xxxxx

I would like to convert this image in base64.

Could someone show me how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need the base64_encode function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

Comment: I know this function, and I´ve used with local image, but my problem is to get facebook picture and use this function.

Comment: copy the image with copy-function: copy("http://facebook/imageurl","/server/path/tmp.jpg"); and then you can encode the image