# PHP CURL returning 301 Location

Tags: php, curl, web

My curl php code is returning 301 and i can't print out what the curl returned. 
this is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://subdomain.thinkific.com/api/public/v1/users/3418346");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "X-Auth-Api-Key: myapikey";
$headers[] = "X-Auth-Subdomain: subdomain";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Here is what it returned:

```
string(142) "301{"Location"=>"https:subdomain.thinkific.com/api/public/v1/users/3418346", "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache"}#"
```

i have tried json_decode the result to print it, still the same. as well as i also tried those:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); //this one returned string(0) without 301
```

I need to know if the error is from my server or it has something to do with my code. ( i did not share api key and subdomain for privacy sorry).

Comment: [You want to follow the 301.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288130/php-curl-following-redirects)

Comment: When i follow the location curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
it gives me error authentication ....

Comment: Then get the `URL` from the `301`. And start a new `cURL`.

Comment: "I can't print out what the curl returned" - 301 responses (normally) don't have a body.

Answer (score 0):

The 301 response code is the following :

> The HTTP response status code 301 Moved Permanently is used for
>   permanent URL redirection, meaning current links or records using the
>   URL that the response is received for should be updated. The new URL
>   should be provided in the Location field included with the response.

SO it means that you're requesting a resource that has been moved (the url changed) and you should retry the request with the newly provided URL !

Comment: The problem was from the platform itself (thinkific) , solved the issue.